# MOSFET conducts current when no gate voltage

Tags: pi-4, troubleshooting, mosfet

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B and a MOSFET IRLB8721PbF (https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/irlb8721pbf.pdf)

I have wired up a simple circuit with an LED, resistor, the MOSFET and a 6V DC power adapter. However, the MOFSET appears to conduct current between the Source and Drain terminal when there is no voltage flowing through the Gate. I am very confused as to why this is the case; I have played around with the wiring to try to get the MOFSET to do its job at stopping current flow when there is no voltage connected to the Gate, but I have had no success.

Here's a photo of my circuit:
https://ibb.co/kqTQrQ7

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you have it wired correctly (as you say you do), your transistor is broken. As an aside, you can't drive a MOSFET from a GPIO  - where did you get such an idea?

Comment: @Seamus OK, I'll bite. Why can't one drive a MOSFET from a GPIO? And I assume you mean **any** MOSFET **whatsoever**, and that "drive" means change the gate voltage when a MOSFET is used as a common-source low-side driver.

Comment: "I'll bite"??? I wish you wouldn't. But you'll learn much more if you research this yourself. Maybe try "minimum gate-source voltage to turn MOSFET on".

Comment: @Seamus Yes, I think it must be broken. The threshold voltage is 2.35 V (look at the data sheet), and Raspberry Pi GPIO pin is 3.3V, so I think it can be powered from a GPIO pin?

Comment: @Seamus I regularly drive MOSFET from GPIO

Comment: @Milliways: I'm surprised, frankly... Maybe you should answer Orlando's question. Even driving the so-called "low threshold" devices is just not something the RPi's GPIO circuitry is equipped to do. I'd be curious to know what applications you've found where a MOSFET out-performs a BJT being driven from an RPi GPIO.

Comment: You didn't read enough. Try [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=gate-source+threshold+voltage&ia=web). If that doesn't help, maybe look at Figure 3 in the data sheet you linked to in your question. What do you think Figure 3 is telling you? How much drain-source current will 3V at the gate give you?

Comment: @Seamus I'd say just under 10A by the looks of it. Anyways, my circuit only needs 0.5A so I really doubt that's the issue...

Comment: You need to read the data sheet for the MOSFET you are using and know the limitation of the gpio.   The gate circuit on a MOSFET needs a minimum voltage Vgs and current to charge the gate to drain and gaye to source capacitance of the MOSFET.  It's unlikely the gpio can drive this particular MOSFET.

Comment: Just to say, I have been in contact with the supplier and the MOSFET was in-fact incorrectly labelled; they have sent the correct one and it is working as expected now!